# How to force refresh of images & css files in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I have a following problem.

I'm coding in CakePHP and I'm a novice. I quite often need to change some images or css files on the website. And on the website I always see the old content unless I manually press "F5" on the keyboard. And I have to do it on every workplace that uses that website.

It is irritating especially because I don't know where I can find the solution for it. I removed tmp files and cookies. Nothing helps and I don't know how can I fix it.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For anything under \webroot, see the `Asset.timestamp` setting in core.php:

```
/**
 * Apply timestamps with the last modified time to static assets (js, css, images).
 * Will append a querystring parameter containing the time the file was modified. This is
 * useful for invalidating browser caches.
 *
 * Set to `true` to apply timestamps when debug > 0. Set to 'force' to always enable
 * timestamping regardless of debug value.
 */
    Configure::write('Asset.timestamp', true);
```

For this to work, you have to use the Cake helpers to create the assets (e.g. `$this->Html->image()`, `$this->Html->css()`, etc)

Comment: Thank you so much! 'Asset.timestamp' was exactly what I needed.

Comment: How to add version to CakePHP asset files (JS and CSS) ?

Comment: Does Cake automatically know to refresh a file with an old timestamp or do you still need to pass it through a Configure css.php filter?  For example I see a command in UrlHelper.php supposedly does this automatically.

Comment: @liquified As long as you use the helpers, Cake will handle the versioning.