# cannot add css versioning with cakePHP html helper

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I wish to add a version number to my css file but I don't see a way to do it with the html helper.

I see one example of adding a timestamp through the bootstrap.php but I want to be able to control the version number myself.

I am using cakephp 2.3

style.min.css?v=1

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->css('style.min', array('v'=>'1'));
    echo $this->fetch('css');
?>
```

or

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->css('style.min?v=1');
    echo $this->fetch('css');
?>
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14493811, but that's for time stamping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the `.css`

```
echo $this->Html->css('style.min.css?v=1');
```

Although it's standard practice to omit the `.css`, it's acceptable to include it, and will allow you to add additional parameters to the end of the URL.

Comment: Thanks, should have thought of that.

Answer (score 3):

In CakePHP 3x you can do this in `config/app.php`.

```
/**
 * Apply timestamps with the last modified time to static assets (js, css, images).
 * Will append a querystring parameter containing the time the file was modified.
 * This is useful for busting browser caches.
 *
 * Set to true to apply timestamps when debug is true. Set to 'force' to always
 * enable timestamping regardless of debug value.
 */
'Asset' => [
    // 'timestamp' => true,
],
```

Comment: And in CakePHP 2.x it's in app/config/core.php. Just uncomment the following:
`Configure::write('Asset.timestamp', true);`
and consider setting it to 'force'.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14493811/1973005